# Visual map of Files

Tags: c, file, directory

I just finished writing a c program that split a very large program into its different components and stored them in a tree like structure using directories and sub directories.

I was wondering if there are any programs that can graph the file system. I'm trying not to have to write my own program to do that if possible.

If possible the program would be easy to use.

Windows or Linux programs would work.

Comment: If you want an existing program and are trying *not* to write code, I think your question would be better on a different site. Perhaps SuperUser SE can help you.

Comment: you want applications(not programs) , to do the task , and such questions are asked at superuser.com

Comment: What about windows explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try WinDirStat, it does pretty much what you ask for.

http://windirstat.info/

There is also a version for linux

http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You are faster than me :)